# combine big join query with duplicate query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am struggling to combine these two sql queries.

```
SELECT players.player_id, players.tag, players.game_race,
       earnings.tournament, earnings.player, earnings.position,
       tournaments.tournament_id, tournaments.region
  FROM players
  JOIN earnings ON players.player_id = earnings.player 
  JOIN tournaments ON earnings.tournament = tournaments.tournament_id
  where position = 1
ORDER BY players.player_id;
```

---

```
SELECT tournament, earnings.player, prize_money, position 
FROM earnings 
join (
    SELECT player FROM earnings 
    where position = 1 group by player having count(player) > 3) 
as DupPlayer
on earnings.player=DupPlayer.player
where position = 1;
```

So I tried with a union.

```
(SELECT players.player_id, players.tag, players.game_race,
       earnings.tournament, earnings.player, earnings.position,
       tournaments.tournament_id, tournaments.region
  FROM players
  JOIN earnings ON players.player_id = earnings.player 
  JOIN tournaments ON earnings.tournament = tournaments.tournament_id
  where position = 1
ORDER BY players.player_id
)
UNION
(
SELECT tournament, earnings.player, prize_money, position 
FROM earnings 
join (
    SELECT player FROM earnings 
    where position = 1 group by player having count(player) > 3) 
as DupPlayer
on earnings.player=DupPlayer.player
where position = 1
);
```

Then I got the error message "The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns". How can I go about fixing this? Is there a better method than union? I really don't wanna change my select statements because I want to see all those columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine the queries like below :

```
SELECT players.player_id, players.tag, players.game_race,
       earnings.tournament, earnings.player, earnings.position,
       tournaments.tournament_id, tournaments.region
  FROM players
  JOIN earnings ON players.player_id = earnings.player 
  JOIN (SELECT player FROM earnings 
        where position = 1 group by player having count(player) > 3) 
        as DupPlayer on earnings.player=DupPlayer.player
  JOIN tournaments ON earnings.tournament = tournaments.tournament_id
  where position = 1
ORDER BY players.player_id;
```